# Alternate library for MatIcon? No insert/delete row icons in Angular MatIcon?

Tags: angular-material, material-design

I am using angular material icons in my project, which implements a spreadsheet like interface for user data.

Unfortunately, MatIcon doesn't seem to supply any suitable icons for row or column inserts/deleted (which I have to say seems like an odd oversight given that there is an icon for "polymer" and "boat_directions".)

Is there some other library that can work with `<mat-icon>` directive?